# Preventing Overwriting of MYSQL data by simultaneous users

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php/MYSQL web site for students to select table seats at a banquet. Once 10 seats are taken the table is no longer available. How can I prevent two or more students booking a seat for themselves & up to 3 guests at the same time? It appears that if two students go in at the same time & try to book seats at the same table, data is overwirtten or more than 10 seats can be allotted. I need a way to ensure the first to try to book seats at a table gets to write to the database before the 2nd user is able to write his selection? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like

```
 UPDATE Seating SET AvailableSeats = AvailableSeats - 4 WHERE TableId = 5 AND AvailableSeats = 7;
```

Where `7` you got from an earlier read.  If this update fails, then you know someone else allocated seats in the meantime.

Comment: +1 This solution would work. However, if you're trying to reserve 4 seats, I'd put `AND AvailableSeats >= 4` because we don't really care if the number of available seats has changed as long as there are enough seats available. This update would get an exclusive lock on the record, so no other queries could even select it. This solves the concurrency issue. Check the number of rows affected to see if you successfully reserved the seats.

Answer (score -1):

i'd check whether the availability still exists immediately before calling the code to make the booking, something like;

```
if (functionToCheckAvailability(number_of_seats)) {
    bookSeats(number_of_seats);
}
```